# JS - Mongoose DEL query issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, express, crud

I'm stumbling on this DELETE query for a specific POST.
It's on a MERN stack, so count **Mongoose** and **Express** in this snippet from app.js :

```
app.delete('/api/post/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  try {
    Post.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Post deleted successfully" });
    console.log(`Post ${req.params.id} deleted`);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

The _id is definitely passing, for my console sends me logs with the exact post _id, but still, it won't be deleted in MongoDB.
Thank you for helping,

Answer (score 1):

Your line `res.status(200).send({ message: "Post deleted successfully" });` and `` console.log(`Post ${req.params.id} deleted`); `` should be wrap like this.

```
Post.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.status(200).send({ message: "Post deleted successfully" });
        console.log(`Post ${req.params.id} deleted`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the thing : needed to make it an async function in order to the Post.delete to take effect.

```
 app.delete('/api/post/delete/:id', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    await Post.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Post deleted successfully" });
    console.log(`Post ${req.params.id} deleted`);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```